# Column 'ID' does not belong to table DefaultView

Tags: c#, gridview, rowdatabound

I have a Gridview "Gridview_ActionPlan" with DataKey "ID" and a RowDataBound event that colors certain cells according to the value of the datasource. Until here everything fine. Now I added a command to give visibility to one column based on a condition and it throws the error "Column 'ID' does not belong to table DefaultView"

```
if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text != "1" && e.Row.Cells[2].Text != "2")
{
    Gridview_ActionPlan.Columns[5].Visible = true;
    LinkButton LB2 = e.Row.Cells[5].FindControl("ButtonOpen") as LinkButton;
    LB2.Visible = true;
}
```

... and Columns[5]

```
        <asp:templatefield ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonOpen" runat="server" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("ID") %>' OnClick="OpenNode" style="vertical-align:text-bottom;text-decoration:none" Visible="false">
                    <asp:Image runat="server" src="img/plus_.png" id="OpenNodeIMG" border="0" Visible="true"/>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:templatefield>
```

Now if I give static visibility to that column and remove "Gridview_ActionPlan.Columns[5].Visible = true;" then no error is thrown. This doesn't make sense to me

### Martin

Here is the full OnRowDataBound event:
Comment: The SQLConnection part fills the grid with the correct headers according to the chosen language. This is kind of time consuming so if someone has a better idea, feel free... although this is not the issue of that post

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var gv = (GridView)sender;
    string GridID = Convert.ToString(gv.ID);

    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXXX");
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(@"select Text
                                             from EPC_Menu
                                             where language = @language and MenuControlID = @GridID
                                             order by MenuID", objConn);
    objCommand.Parameters.Add("@GridID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = GridID;
    objCommand.Parameters.Add("@language", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LanguageLabel.Text;
    DataSet t = new DataSet();
    adapter.SelectCommand = objCommand;
    objConn.Open();
    adapter.Fill(t);
    objConn.Close();

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i+6 < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (t.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i+6].Text = t.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "True")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[9].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF00");
            e.Row.Cells[10].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF00");
        }
        else if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "2")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCECF4");
        }
        if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text != "1" && e.Row.Cells[2].Text != "2" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[3].Text) && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && Gridview_ActionPlan.EditIndex != e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            LinkButton LB2 = e.Row.Cells[5].FindControl("ButtonOpen") as LinkButton;
            LB2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

here goes the gridview with columns 0 - 5 is already posted:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview_ActionPlan" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="ActionPlan" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    Font-Names="Arial" 
    OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <RowStyle BorderColor="White" 
        Font-Size="12px" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" 
            ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" 
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerRequired" 
            ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" 
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" 
            ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" 
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CNT" 
            ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" 
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" 
            ItemStyle-Width="50px" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="LINKButton2" runat="server" 
                    CommandName="Edit" 
                    ImageUrl="img/edit.png" 
                    Style="vertical-align: text-bottom" />&nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonSelect" runat="server" 
                    CommandName="Select" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' 
                    Style="vertical-align: text-bottom; text-decoration: none" 
                    OnClick="AddNewMileStone" Visible="true">
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ImageMS" 
                            ImageUrl="img/select.png" 
                            Style="vertical-align: text-bottom; text-decoration: none" 
                            BorderStyle="None" />
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" 
                    CommandName="Update" 
                    ImageUrl="img/save.png" 
                    Style="vertical-align: text-bottom" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:ImageButton ID="LINKButton2" runat="server" 
                    CommandName="Cancel" 
                    ImageUrl="img/cancel2.jpg" 
                    Style="vertical-align: text-bottom" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" 
            Visible="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonOpen" runat="server" 
                CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("ID") %>' 
                OnClick="OpenNode" 
                style="vertical-align:text-bottom;text-decoration:none" 
                Visible="false">
                <asp:Image id="OpenNodeIMG" runat="server" 
                    src="img/plus_.png" 
                    border="0" 
                    Visible="true"/>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Is the first snippet from the OpenNode event handler? What's the full method and where exactly the exception is thrown?

Comment: No, this is the OnRowDataBound event. And the exception is thrown while binding the Grid and caused by setting Gridview_ActionPlan.Columns[5].Visible = true

Comment: I think that sharing also the stack trace could be helpful

Comment: Don't know what you want as the stack trace. I added the whole OnRowDataBound method. I basically reduced everything to the minimum code to make things easier to capture

Comment: would like to see your gridview markup too

Comment: Thanks for your support. I just added it

Comment: so you have these six columns only.

Comment: if you only 6 columns, `e.Row.Cells[i+6].Text` for the header row doesn't make any sense?

Comment: there are 8 plain data template fields with just labels bound to the SQLDATASOURCE that I didn't post because they wouldn't give any hint on this issue.

Comment: Try/catch that line and copy/paste the exc.StackTrace **if** you still need a specific answer about the original error...

Answer (score 0):

> This is kind of time consuming so if someone has a better idea, feel free... although this is not the issue of that post

Actually this should be a major issue. You are doing three things wrong here.

1. You are calling the function to fill the dataset in each iteration of RowDataBound. If you have 20 rows and 1 header that will be 20 unnecessary call to database
2. No need to open() the connection to fill a dataset using a data-adapter
3. No need to qualify `.FindControl` with Cells[cell_index]`.

So move your code after your Gridviews DataBind() event. Pseudo code will be,

```
Gridview_ActionPlan.DataBind();
DataSet t = new DataSet();
var gv = Gridview_ActionPlan;
string GridID = Convert.ToString(gv.ID);

using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXXX"))
using (SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(@"select Text
                                    from EPC_Menu
                                    where language = @language and MenuControlID = @GridID
                                    order by MenuID", objConn))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    objCommand.Parameters.Add("@GridID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = GridID;
    objCommand.Parameters.Add("@language", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LanguageLabel.Text;
    adapter.SelectCommand = objCommand;
    adapter.Fill(t);
}

var headerRow = gv.HeaderRow;
for (int i = 0; i + 6 < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (t.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        headerRow.Cells[i + 6].Text = t.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (gv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == "True")
    {
        gv.Rows[i].Cells[9].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF00");
        gv.Rows[i].Cells[10].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF00");
    }
    else if (gv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text == "2")
    {
        gv.Rows[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCECF4");
    }
    if (gv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text != "1" && 
        gv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text != "2" && 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(gv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text) &&
        gv.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && 
        Gridview_ActionPlan.EditIndex != gv.Rows[i].RowIndex)
    {
        LinkButton LB2 = gv.Rows[i].FindControl("ButtonOpen") as LinkButton;
        LB2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You gave me a lot of input and homework to study. BUT, if I apply this modification to my code it throws the error "Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely"

Comment: Do you know where this happens?

Comment: No, unfortunately not exactly. On loading that gridview

Comment: To isolate the mistake I eliminated all conditions, leaving only the first part until var headerRow = gv.HeaderRow; the grid is not loaded. It tries to, but after a while the "Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely" error is thrown. There might be another hint: I had copy & pasted that first part you posted into my OnRowDataBound method and that error showed up. Only then I realized that I hadn't changed the connection string that in my post was blurred ("XXXX"); nevertheless that didn't throw an error. Which means that a connection is not even tried to be established

Comment: Naveen, I'm a bit lost. I see your point on the unnecessary calling of the function on every iteration for each cell. But I can't see how to avoid it, as in my understanding every piece of code in the OnRowDataBound method is executed on each and every cell. I don't understand how your pseudo code could work. Right now I'm thinking of the following: As the filling of the grid is triggered by selecting a row of another grid, I could have an invisible aux Grid be filled with the headers in the IndexSelectionChange event and then refer to that aux Grid while Binding the header row of the Grid

Comment: what is the code trying to achieve. i am a bit confused at that part

Comment: I'm having a multi-language page and therefore the headers of the grid have to be fetched according to the selected language, while the content of the grid is provided by the SQL DataSource. So, now I'm building the headers table in a prior step outside the OnRowDataBound event with all its iterations. And it's much faster!

Comment: is there a way where you can use datatable to bind grid?